# Avoid repetitive launch when emitting value using Flow, StateFlow, SharedFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, coroutinescope

I am migrating from `LiveData` to Coroutine Flows specifically `StateFlow` and `SharedFlow`. Unfortunately emitting values should run on a CoroutineScope thus you have this ugly repetitive code `viewModelScope.launch` when using it inside a ViewModel. Is there an optimal way of emitting values from this?

```
class MainSharedViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    private val mainActivityState = MutableSharedFlow<MainActivityState>()

    fun getMainActivityState(): SharedFlow<MainActivityState> = mainActivityState

    fun setTitle(title: String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mainActivityState.emit(ToolbarTitleState(title))
        }
    }

    fun filterData(assetName: String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mainActivityState.emit(AssetFilterState(assetName))
        }
    }

    fun limitData(limit: Int){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mainActivityState.emit(AssetLimitState(limit))
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tryEmit()` instead of `emit()`. `tryEmit()` is non-suspending. The reason it's "try" is that it won't emit if the flow's buffer is currently full and set to SUSPEND instead of dropping values when full.

Note, you have no buffer currently because you left `replay` as 0. You should keep a replay of at least `1` so values aren't missed when there is a configuration change on your Activity/Fragment.

Example:

```
fun setTitle(title: String){
    mainActivityState.tryEmit(ToolbarTitleState(title))
}
```

Alternatively, you can use MutableStateFlow, which always has a replay of 1 and can have its value set by using `value =`, just like a LiveData.

Comment: I don't get the replay part, is this implicit in my current code? Thanks

Comment: I want to use StateFlow but it requires a default value, should I create a new state which do nothing? I do not want to emit something upon initialization.

Comment: Any downside of using `tryEmit`? What is the limited buffer means?

Comment: `replay` defaults to 0. It is a parameter for `MutableSharedFlow()`. StateFlow requires an initial value, and if nothing has been emitted yet, collectors will receive that default value. If you don't want that behavior, use a MutableSharedFlow with `replay` of 1 and `onBufferOverflow` of DROP_OLDEST. Then `tryEmit` will be guaranteed to always succeed. It can only fail if `onBufferOverflow` is SUSPEND. If you set `onBufferOverflow` to SUSPEND, which is the default value, then if there is at least one collector that collects slower than you are emitting, `tryEmit` can fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot, by the way is this a bad practice or not?

Comment: Which way? I’m not suggesting bad practices to you.

Comment: by using `tryEmit` just so I can emit without any CoroutineScope

Comment: Its fine but you need to decide on the behavior you want—whether it should drop the oldest value or not emit if a collector is falling behind. If you’re emitting on the main thread and collecting on the main dispatcher, it doesn’t matter because the collector won’t fall behind.

Comment: There is another parameter `extraBufferCapacity`, what should be its value?

Comment: Also why should `DROP_OLDEST` and not `DROP_LATEST`? Thanks

Comment: You can choose which makes sense. Usually you want to have the most up to date data to show in your UI, though so you will usually want to drop older values. You probably don’t need any extra buffer. If you’re not doing something with ongoing data analysis, like processing audio data, you probably want replay of 1 and extra capacity of 0.

Comment: How about when collecting? Should I use `collect` or `collectLatest` to make SharedFlow behave similar to LiveData.

Comment: I noticed that applying `distinctUntilChanged()` also makes SharedFlow behave like StateFlow

Comment: `collect` is more like LiveData, since LiveData has no mechanism for cancelling processing in the listener, since that listener is not suspending. But `collectLatest()` might make more sense if your collector has any suspend functions in it and you just want to show the latest data anyway. Depends if it might start falling behind though. `distinctUntilChanged()` is one of the behaviors that StateFlow has automatically, so that does make SharedFlow behave closer to StateFlow. That is not a behavior that LiveData has.

Comment: I read some article https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=uzVTEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT255&lpg=PT255&dq=DROP_LATEST+vs+DROP_OLDEST&source=bl&ots=CoR_XTv_z6&sig=ACfU3U2YJ534mdeLxXKfDnYS1avPCgDAwg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj74NiQ-af2AhVyKaYKHR3LCwgQ6AF6BAgaEAM#v=onepage&q=DROP_LATEST%20vs%20DROP_OLDEST&f=false, it says setting `extraBufferCapacity` to 1 and `onBufferOverflow` to `DROP_OLDEST` will make `tryEmit` always success.

Comment: That's what I was saying in the answer. If you set it to anything besides SUSPEND, `tryEmit` will always succeed, regardless of buffer size.

Comment: Does it behave like `LiveData` when the orientation has been change where it fires up all the collector again?

Comment: It’s the other way around. The LiveData doesn’t fire up collectors again. After an orientation change, all observers are automatically removed, but the Activity/Fragment is what presumably adds its new observers when it is recreated. So it is up to the Activity/Fragment to re-observe, and it’s the same way with Flows.